# Mysql performance with AND NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

We have this sql-query that has been working fine in mssql
It works in mysql as well but takes too long.
Anyone see any obvious way to imporve the performance of this query?

```
  SELECT MAX(ProjectIssue.CompletionDate) as 'CompletionDate', ProjectIssue.CurrentOwnerSystemUserId,
 COUNT(DISTINCT ProjectIssue.ProjectIssueId) 
 FROM ProjectIssue 
 INNER JOIN Project ON ProjectIssue.ProjectId = Project.ProjectId 
 WHERE ProjectIssue.ProjectId IN (10954,7805,5847,4381,123,17965,5183,378,20,10535) 
 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT ToStatus FROM IssueHistory WHERE IssueHistory.ProjectIssueId = 
 ProjectIssue.ProjectIssueId   
 GROUP BY ToStatus HAVING COUNT(ToStatus) > 1) 
 AND ProjectIssue.CreateDate >= '2021-01-01'
 AND ProjectIssue.CreateDate <= '2021-01-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

`IssueHistory` needs `INDEX(ProjectIssueId, ToStatus)`

You can probably get rid of the use of table `Project`, it seems to add nothing to the query.

What is the relationship between the tables?  That is, are these true:

1 Project has 1 or more "issues"?  Or maybe 0 or more?

1 issue has 1 or more "history" rows?

(Depending on the answers, I may need to revise my answer.)

The `NOT EXISTS` could be reformulated thus.  I do not know whether it would be faster or slower; experiment with them:

```
AND ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ToStatus) FROM IssueHistory
            WHERE  IssueHistory.ProjectIssueId = ProjectIssue.ProjectIssueId
    ) <= 1
```

or maybe

```
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT DISTINCT ToStatus
            FROM  IssueHistory
            WHERE  IssueHistory.ProjectIssueId = ProjectIssue.ProjectIssueId
            LIMIT 1,1
               )
```

If `CreateDate` is a `DATETIME`, then the where clause leaves out most of the last day of January.  This phrasing works in all cases:

```
      AND  ProjectIssue.CreateDate >= '2021-01-01'
      AND  ProjectIssue.CreateDate  < '2021-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```